# Why is url() outputting two '//'s?

Tags: 6, uri, redirection

```
  $form_state['redirect'] = url('node/add/media/' . $form_state['nid']);
```

When I get redirected it ends up at "http://mysite.net//node/add/media/772"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be talking out my you know what, but just try:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/media/' . $form_state['nid'];
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't have the same problem. I feel like I must have some setting that's messing me up. $base_path is '/', should it perhaps be just ''?

Comment: That would definitely do it.

Comment: @Joren have a look at the value of `$base_url` in your `setting.php` it shouldn't end with a `/`.

Comment: Hmm I don't even have $base_url set in my settings.php. Does it default to '/' or am I setting it elsewhere?

Comment: Well adding $base_url = 'http://siteurl.com' with no trailing slash fixed the problem. I don't know where it was getting the '/' value it was set to from.